# Is there any way to hint to autolayout to make a view as small as possible while respecting constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

So I have a view, `v`, which I want to constrain in the following way:

- `v` has a minimum size: `m`
- `v` should scale horizontally to fit the text view contained inside, `t`
- `v` should be centered inside the superview, `s`
- `v` should be as small as possible.

So I have tried to achieve this with the following constraints:

```
v.width >= m
v.width >= t.width
v.centerX == s.centerX
```

With these constraints, the problem is that the view grows to fill the entirety of the superview.

If I remove the constraint `v.width >= m` then  the view scales to wrap `t` as closely as possilble.

Is there anyway to hint to auto layout that it should try to make `v` as small as possible without breaking the constraints?

Comment: I think setting the horizontal/vertical content hugging priorities to 1000 (required) might do the trick, but I'm not 100% sure I understand your view hierarchy and the desired outcome. A drawing might help.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying width/height with inequalities you generally need to have opposite >= and <=

```
v.width >= m
v.width <= t.width
```

This way if t.width is > m, then there's an answer for how wide satisfies both equations.

But t.width could be < m, so you need different priorities:
If you have two >= priorities then there's ambiguity about how much greater the value should be to satisfy all the equations

```
v.width >= m, priority .defaultHigh
v.width <= t.width, priority .defaultLow
```

Now if t.width is < m then it will just ignore the default low priority and v.width will be m